# Ad management control panel

Tags: usability

We have a rather complex web service that allows users to submit private selling ads. Other users of the service can "apply" to those ads and chat about each one. Each seller can have multiple applications for a single ad and decide which one he/she wants to sell product to.

Our interface looks like this:

[image: Interface]

When buyer applies for a product, seller receives notification about that. And now it looks like this:

[image: Interface with badges]

There's a badge in main navigation (My deals), when you open that page, there's a second and third navigation that splits sellers and buyers, and splits ads by its status (ended or inactive ads also can receive notifications).

So, for each message there are 4 badges visible on a page, that guides user to the place where you should open your messages.

We tried to make two different pages where on one you see only messages and on another there is all submitted ads, but it was very confusing for users - the same ad was in two places simultaneously.

We are looking for a way to reduce badge count or make some alternatives to badges. We tried to highlight tabs instead of putting badge there, but visually it was looking as the tab was selected.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to include "Notifications" menu item to reduce the clutter on the UI. When there is a new notification(s), the color of "Notifications" menu item would turn to '**red**'.

Clicking on the "Notifications" menu item would display a modal overlay that shows the latest x number of comments/feedbacks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try reduce navigation levels by:

- make buyer/seller a top level user profile decision - similar to having multiple google accounts, airbnb or uber
- as for published, ended, inactive you could try to change tabs to filters, with the most likely option (published) preselected
- as for badges - depends how different they are and what purpose they serve, you could use those as labels on the list and provide a filter for them. Then obe notification place is needed, that upon clicking on a message, directly redirects you to it, with an option to go back to the main list